# How to assign value from a char into a pointer?

Tags: c, function, validation

In function input, I was trying to do an input validation that will only accept input from the given choices. I tried using only the variable opt to get the values from scanf but when I compare with if, it gives an error saying something about comparing a pointer to another type.

With this code, I kinda managed to make that error disappear and the program now runs but the program ends after I input the choice. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int add(int n1, int n2);
int subtract(int n1, int n2);
int multiply(int n1, int n2);
int divide(int n1, int n2);
void input(int *n1, int *n2, char *opt);


int main(void)
{
    int n1, n2, ret;
    char opt;

    start:
    input(&n1, &n2, &opt);

    switch(opt)
{
            case '1': 
                ret = add(n1, n2);
                printf("The sum is %d\n", ret);
                break;
            case '2':
                ret = subtract(n1, n2);
                printf("The difference is %d\n", ret);
                break;
            case '3': 
                ret = multiply(n1, n2);
                printf("The product is %d\n", ret); 
                break;              
            case '4': 
                ret = divide(n1, n2);
                printf("The quotient is %d\n", ret);
                break;
            case 'R':
                goto start;
                break;
            case 'E':
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                return 0;
                break;
    }
    return 0;   
}


void input(int *n1, int *n2, char *opt)
{
    int valid;
    char choice;

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n1);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n2);   

    getchar();
    valid = 0;
    while( valid == 0)
    {
        printf("Addition -> 1\nSubtraction -> 2\nMultiplication -> 3\nDivision -> 4\nReset -> R\nExit -> E\n");


        if ( scanf("%c", &choice) == ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E'))
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }
    }
    opt = &choice;

}


int add(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1+n2);
    return result;
}

int subtract(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1-n2);
    return result;
}

int divide(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1/n2);
    return result;
}

multiply(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1*n2);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You might need to read about what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) actually returns. Then you need to read up on how conditions in C works.

Comment: afaik, scanf here scans for the user's input. That's why I compared the scanned value with the valid inputs. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, and you would know why if you followed the link in my previous comment and read the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One* of the problems with the program you show is that it will not give you the option entered. That's because arguments are passed by value in C, which means that arguments are *copied* and changing an argument will not change the original value.

This is noticeable when you do

```
opt = &choice;
```

This reassignment of the `opt` pointer will be lost once the function returns.

What you want in this specific case is to use the *dereference* operator to dereference the pointer you pass in, and assign the value of `choice` to the dereferenced pointer:

```
*opt = choice;
```

---

There are many other errors in your code, including one which you don't notice because it works but not in the way you expect it to.

Lets take the condition

```
scanf("%c", &choice) == ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E')
```

The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function returns the number of successfully parsed formats, or `EOF`. In your case it would return `1` if it read and parsed a character.

The expression `('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E')` is the one that doesn't work as expected. In C all non-zero values are considered "true", only zero is "false". If your system is using the [ASCII alphabet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (most likely) then the expression

```
('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E')
```

is equivalent to

```
(49 || 50 || 51 || 52 || 82 || 69)
```

All of the sub-expressions are "true" leading to the while expression to be "true" which in C is equivalent to `1`.

So the expression

```
scanf("%c", &choice) == ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E')
```

is equivalent to

```
scanf("%c", &choice) == 1
```

which is what you *should* check for, but not in this way.

What you should do is to put a check *inside* the loop for the correct alternative, but remember what I said the result of `('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || 'R' || 'E')` would be.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But it didn't notify about the wrong input. DId I do anything wrong with the input validation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't actually get what you're saying regarding putting a check for the correct alternative. I'm really sorry. I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @fixotherm Either an `if` statement, or a `switch` statement. E.g. `if (choice != '1' && choice != '2' ...) { printf("Wrong alternative\n"); }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer explains why your code doesn't work very well, so here is a working version of your input() function and a bit shorter version of the operator functions:

```
void input(int *n1, int *n2, char *opt)
{
    int valid;
    char choice = '0';

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n1);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n2);   

    getchar();
    valid = 0;
    while( valid == 0)
    {
        printf("Addition -> 1\nSubtraction -> 2\nMultiplication -> 3\nDivision -> 4\nReset -> R\nExit -> E\n");

        choice = getchar();
        switch (choice) {
            case ('1', '2', '3', '4', 'R', 'E'):
                valid = 1;
                break;
            default: printf("Invalid input!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    *opt = choice;
}
```

and the operators you can just do

```
int add(n1, n2)
{
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Comment: terminal says case label does not reduce to an integer constant. O.O

and what does the extra getchar do? O.o